# Request Time Expression (XML Syntax) %= %

Tags: java, xml, jsp, runtime, jspx

While taking an OCWCD practice exam (Whizlabs), I ran across some syntax I haven't seen before (and can't seem to find a clear explanation of).

Question: Which of the following is valid in a JSP document?

Correct answer: `<jsp:include page="%=pageName%"/>`

The explanation states,

> For a request time expression in XML syntax, we have to use `%= %`. Also note that the JSP syntax uses `<%= %>` syntax for request time expressions.

I'm clear on the JSP syntax, but I'm not familiar with `%= %`. Can anyone explain to me the `%= %` syntax used here? I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions:  <%! %> declaration, <%= =%> scripting expression, scriptlet, and the others, are not valid as syntax in a XML document, so to make it compatible with JSP XML syntax  we need to use the corresponding expression %= =, You should check this article [JSP XML Support](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97688_16/generic.903/a97679/jspxml.htm)

Comment: So, to clarify: Is it correct to say that `%=%` simply allows for inclusion of a runtime expression within a JSP document? (Similarly to the JSP expression syntax `<%= %>` within a plain JSP)?

Comment: Yes it is, both of them are request-time attribute expression, and simply allows the inclusion of the expressions in the JSP document.